# Cannot get a welcome ViewController to show only once with UserDefaults (Swift)

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I am trying to detect whether this is a user's first time visit and show a welcome screen if that's the case, but I can't seem to get it working and I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. I looked at a few of the suggestions here and followed them and I thought I understood the concept but I cannot get this to work.

I get sent straight to the ViewController even though I tried erasing all content and settings in the simulator.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:

**AppDelegate under func didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var vc: UIViewController?
    var ud = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "UDisFirstVisit")

    if ud == true {
        print("This is the user's first visit")
        vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Welcome_01")
    } else if ud == false {
        print ("This is NOT the user's first visit")
        vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
    }


    self.window?.rootViewController = vc
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
```

**Welcome_01** (the Welcome VC)

```
import UIKit

var isFirstVisit = true

class Welcome_01: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func finishedwelcome(_ sender: Any) {
        isFirstVisit = false
        UserDefaults.standard.set(isFirstVisit, forKey: "UDisFirstVisit")
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
```

**UIViewController** (the VC supposed to show after the first visit).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
```

Comment: `ud` will never be true!

Comment: Ok, do you know why?

Comment: What would ever make it true? Think about what will happen the very first time. What will `ud` be?

Comment: Is it because, my ViewController is the initialVC so Welcome_01 never gets loaded so var isFirstVisit = true is never parsed. Should I then declare isFirstVisit in ViewController then or under AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trace through the action in your imagination. What will happen the very first time the user runs the app?

```
var ud = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "UDisFirstVisit")
```

Well, no entry has ever been made into user defaults. So `ud` is not `true`, because it isn't *anything* — it doesn't exist! So it is `false`. So your welcome view controller is never seen.

Just reverse your logic. Start by asking if a key `"UserHasSeenWelcome"` is *false*. If it is, show the welcome v.c. and set the key to `true`.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, I did what you suggested and it worked :D. Thanks a lot Matt.

Answer (score 0):

When an app is first installed, there are no values for any of your UserDefaults keys. So when you do:

```
var ud = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "UDisFirstVisit")
```

on the non-existent `UDisFirstVisit` key, you will get back `false`.

From the documentation for `bool(forKey:)`:

> The Boolean value associated with the specified key. If the specified key doesn‘t exist, this method returns false.

You have two options.

1. Reverse your logic. Have a `UDhasVisited` key that is set to `true` once you first show the welcome screen. On startup, if it is `false`, show the welcome screen.
2. Add the following line to your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

   ```
   UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: [ "UDisFirstVisit": true ])
   ```

Pick one of the two (not both).

Comment: "Reverse your logic" snap :)